# A set of Real numbers that contains all elements of a closed Interval except an open interval within it. x in {[0,4]- (1,2)}

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I don't know if this question has been asked before.
Suppose we have a set of Real Numbers such that

$ A =[0,4] \\ B = (1,2) $

$ X = \{x \in \{A - B\} \} $

or in general it contains all the elements of a closed interval except the elements of an open interval thats a proper subset of the closed interval.

Is X now a closed set?

By the definition a Real Number Set is closed if it contains all of its its limit points.

and **s** is a limit point of set **S** if

$ \forall \epsilon \gt 0 , \exists \  a\ne s  $ such that
$ a \in \{ V_{\epsilon(s)} \cap S \} $

Now I can intuitively think of that any elements in (1,2) cannot be a limit point of set X. And neither can be any elements of Real numbers outside of the closed set [0,4].

Did it come out as a valid conclusion?

Comment: You realise that $[0,4]\setminus(1,2)=[0,1]\cup[2,4]$ - the union of two closed sets?

Comment: Your notation is (at least) confusing. Do you mean to say that $X=A-B$? Be aware that $\{a\}$ is the notation for the set that only contains $a$ as element. I have never seen notations like $\{x\in\{A-B\}\}$ before.

Comment: You just need to prove your intuition using contradiction.

Comment: YesI meant $\backslash$. Thats why I also explained it in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by {$x \in {A - B}$} the set of all subtractions with $a\in A, b\in B$ so $a-b \in X$, then you have an open set, because the least number you can get is $0 - (2)$ but $-2$ is not in the set and the biggest number you can get is $4-1$ but as $1$ is also not in the set, the final set (or interval) is $X= (-2,3)$.

But if you mean $X=A \setminus B$ then you have $X=[0,1] \cup [2,4]$ as 1 and 2 has to be in the set, but all the other numbers between aren't.